# Is it correct to say "I shook water off the vegetables but the basket slipped out my hand"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Sometimes, we would like to eat **raw** salads or other vegetables. We have to wash the vegetables first, then **try to get rid of water on the vegetables** before we eat them.

To get rid of water on the vegetables, we often put the vegetables in a basket with holes, then we **move** the basket with full of vegetables **up and down quickly**. Because of the gravity and the momentum, the vegetables will stay in the basket and won't fall out. But sometimes, the vegetables may fall out if it is not done carefully or the whole basket drops down (see the picture below).

[image]

How to express "move the basket with full of vegetables **up and down quickly**"?

For example, "**I shook water off the vegetables but the basket slipped out my hand**".

Comment: "slipped out _of_ my hand..." in current U.S. English. Dropping the "of" does not impair intelligibility, though it strongly indicates that the speaker/writer is not a native speaker in any anglophone country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the West you can buy special wire baskets for shaking the water off salad leaves - https://www.etsy.com/market/wire_salad_basket , or 'salad spinners' where turning a handle makes the basket spin round very fast so as to throw off the water.

> I shook the salad dry, but accidentally dropped the basket.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "slipped out my hand" is not correct here, indeed I don't think that phrase is ever correct. It should be "slipped out **of** my hand".

With that correction the sentence is understandable, but does not fully convey the situation you describe. An additional sentence would be probably needed to fully clarify this.

(By the way, the picture is not really needed to make the situation clearer for this question.)